# Не работает второй onclick в controller

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не видит numberone1 в controller.js

```
<form:select  id="sel" path="username" onclick="numberone();numberone1">
```

Comment: что значит `видеть` в вашем случае?

Comment: numberone - выполняет действие, а numberone1 - не выполняет в controller

Comment: посмотрите внимательно, как вы написали вызов первой функции и второй

Comment: Если про скобки numberone1(), то ничего не изменилось

Comment: значит, ошибка не здесь и с этим кодом мы вряд ли вам поможем

Comment: numberone1 это функция которую нужно выполнить или переменная?

Comment: numberone1 это функция